# Migrating/Upgrading a MySQL 5.1 schema to MySQL 5.7 schema

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, mysql-5.1, mysql-5.7

I'm bit green on MySQL upgrades, but my question has to do with single schemas (dbs).  I have some hosted databases on a server using MySQL 5.1 Community, and I currently use mysqldump to back those databases up.  When I go to restore them into the MySQL 5.7 server, do I need to run an upgrade on those databases to bring them "up to speed"?

The mysql_upgrade command seems to be related to all database within an instance, and I will be moving dbs one at a time into the server that has had dbs created from scratch there, as well as other dbs that have been moved to it from the previous version (5.1).

Comment: back them up using mysqldump on 5.1 and restore them on 5.7 and then you don't have to run mysql_upgrade.

Comment: That was my plan, but does that leave me simply running a 5.1 formatted database in a 5.7 instance, or does the restore process make all the necessary translations?  My 5.1 instance has the standard options declared, and the 5.7 is using the new default of InnoDB File-Per-Table Tablespaces.  Any issues there?

Comment: shouldn't be an issue rather it is standard procedure to take backup using mysqldump and restore and if  InnoDB File-Per-Table is enabled it will take effect as desired. Hope it helps

Comment: difference could be in sql_mode settings and legacy table structure. Such as - 0000-00-00 00:00:00 default dates. By default they disabled in 5.7, so or upgrade schemas before, or set sql_mode = 0 and upgrade after

Answer (score 3):

Some things, such as microsecond in TIMESTAMP, will automatically be available because the `CREATE TABLE` on 5.7 will use the new format.  `innodb_file_per_table` has a new default, so the tables will be laid out differently.  That should not be a problem.

`mysql_upgrade` is for converting the `mysql` tables and for `ALTERing` to accommodate microseconds, etc, in an *existing* mysql instance where you are updating the software, not where you are loading the data.

Coming forward from 4.0 can cause troubles with changed syntax, the addition of `CHARACTER SET`, etc.  But 5.1 is not that much different *for what you are doing* than 5.7.

There have been lots of changes/additions to `mysql`, `information_schema`, and `performance_schema`.  So, be sure not to dump and reload them.

Use pt-show-grants if you need to carry `GRANTs` forward.  Then check the results.

Do you have specific examples of things that concern you?